# nested attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I am trying to build a small recipe website. But when I try to use nested attribute for saving my child(recipe_ingredients) table through parent(recipe) action. It only generating ids for me without any data in it. Could any one help?

Model for recipe:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Model for recipe_ingredients:

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

Controller for recipe:

```
 def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  @recipe.recipe_ingredients.build
  ***binding.pry***

 if @recipe.save
   render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe
 else
   render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
end

 def recipe_params
   params.require(:recipes)
    .permit(:name, :category, instruction: [], recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:amount, :ingredient, :measure])
 end
```

```

After I check with rails console, my recipe_params is like below

`[7] pry(#<RecipesController>)> recipe_params
Unpermitted parameter: recipe_ingredients
=> {"name"=>"an example recipe", "category"=>"fry", "instructions"=>["do it", "ignore it"]}`

I don't know how to solve that "Unpermitted parameter" problem. Please help~ Thank you~

Comment: Update: Above problem solved, it's my curl request is causing the problem. I didn't specify "recipe_ingredients_attributes" for my data. But rails help me to saving data for recipe_ingredients table and also one line of empty data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change params.require(:recipes) in your recipe_params method to params.require(:recipe)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you~ I forget to specify "recipe_ingredients_attributes" in my curl. Problem solve~ If it's possible, would you mind check out another question of nested attributes questions for me? Many thanks~http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679639/update-nested-attributes-in-rails