# Update nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, nested-attributes

I am having trouble with updating my nested attributes when I sending patch request. I want to update my recipe_ingredients when I update my recipe. Every time when I update my recipe, recipe gets updated, but recipe_ingredients are just appending for that recipe. Please help~ Many thanks~

Recipe Controller

```

```
  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
       @recipe_ingredients = @recipe.recipe_ingredients.all
       head :no_content
    else
       render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipes)
        .permit(:name, :category, instructions: [],  recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :recipe_id, :ingredient, :measure, :amount])
end
```

```

Recipe Model:

```

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :recipe_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true
end
```

```

Curl Request:
```

```
   curl --include --request PATCH http://localhost:3000/recipes/1 \
   --header "Authorization: Token token=..." \
   --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data '{
      "recipes": {
      "name": "second example recipe",
      "category": "grill",
      "instructions": ["do it", "ignore it"],
      "recipe_ingredients_attributes": [{
                                         "amount": 1,
                                         "ingredient": "egg yolk",
                                         "measure": "cup"
                                        },
                                        {
                                         "amount": 3,
                                         "ingredient": "soy milk",
                                         "measure": "cup"
                                        }]
      }
    }'
```

```

Comment: Please post the `form_for` portion of the view that handles this update.

Comment: I don't have a form_for portion. I haven't create my front end yet. I am just trying to make curl request to test whether it works or not;

Comment: How about your `recipe.rb` then, in order to double check the relationships? I'm not 100% sure because I've never tested nested attributes without a form, but using `form_for` may make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `id` of your `recipe_ingredients` in the curl request for rails to update the correct existing `recipe_ingredient` records. Otherwise, rails will create a new record. For example, this will update `recipe_ingredient` with `id 1` and create new "soy milk" ingredient:

```
"recipe_ingredients_attributes": [{
                                    "id": 1
                                    "amount": 1,
                                    "ingredient": "egg yolk",
                                    "measure": "cup"
                                   },
                                   {
                                    "amount": 3,
                                    "ingredient": "soy milk",
                                    "measure": "cup"
                                   }]
```

Comment: Yes. This can fix the problem. But I am not sure how to keep track of recipe_ingredients' id every time when I create new recipe. Since recipe_ingredients are nested attributes for recipe. I want to update them when I update my recipe. Is there any rails "trick" for keep track of child id when create parent or update parent? Thanks for your suggestion~

Comment: When you want to update a recipe, you need to fetch its data first to display, right? I mean you have to `show` before `update`. Thus, in the `show` action, you return ids of every ingredient of that recipe so that you know which ingredient you are updating to send correct id. And when creating a recipe, you are creating new ingredients, so there's no need to know their id.